# Creating Outlook Contacts via Applescript

Tags: outlook, applescript

I'm trying to create an Outlook contact via Applescript. The script looks like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to make new contact with properties {first name:"test1", last name:"test2", email addresses:{{address:"work@mywork.com", type:work}, {address:"home@myhome.com", type:home}}}
```

The Outlook dictionary tells me that I got the class name ("contact") and the field names right. But upon saving the script I'm told: expected class name, but got property and the first "name" is highlighted. Strangely enough this error goes away if I remove the space between "first" and "name" (and "last" and "name").
Then I can save it, but upon executing I get this: 
error "The variable „contact“ is not defined." number -2753 from "contact" (my translation, the original error message is in german). I'm using Outlook 2011 (v14.3.9 on Mavericks). What might be up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works. Try looking somewhere else in the script. Paste the snippet above into a new script and test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, hmm, bizarre, I keep getting the error message, also in a brand new script. I'm using the Applescript editor 2.6 (153), fwiw.

Comment: Works in both Applescript editor Version 2.6 (152) and Script Debugger 5.0.7

Comment: Got it working now. What I did is this: I deleted the word "Microsoft". Then I saved again. The Applescript editor put the word "Microsoft" back in and recognized the field and class names. Seems the Application name doesn't always get recognized properly, which also explains why it couldn't deal with contacts and first and last names. Oh well...